# Check meta tag exist on web-page using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, meta-tags

I want to check a meta tag exist on webpage.

I have tried this :

```
document.getElementsByTagName("meta[http-equiv:Content-Type]").length
```

But this alway return 0. How can I do that? I want to do it by using javascript. Not jQuery.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var x = document.querySelector('meta[http-equiv="Content-Type"]');
console.log(x);
```

`x` has a reference to the meta tag if found. It will be `null` otherwise, so you can use `if (x) {`

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UqiDino/8/edit)**

Here's a way to do it if `querySelectorAll` isn't supported (older browsers)

```
var metas = document.getElementsByTagName('meta');

var found;
for (var i=0; i<metas.length; ++i) {
  var meta = metas[i];
  if (meta.getAttribute('http-equiv') === "Content-Type") {
    found = meta;
    break;
  }
}

console.log(found);
```

**[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/UqiDino/3/edit)**

`found` has a reference to the meta tag if it existed. You could do `if (found) {` to determine whether or not it exists.

Comment: You don't even need to check the length, just use `querySelector` and make sure it returns something other than null would suffice.

Comment: Hmm.. I've tested on Chrome and IE9 and I'm getting null if it's not there.

Comment: @kei Oh, you mean without the "All" that actually doesn't work for this. It will fail if there is another meta tag on the page before the one with attribute we're looking for.

Comment: @m59 No, not when the selector is already testing for the presence of the attribute value.

Comment: Yeah, I accidentally left `.length` on the thing I was logging when using `querySelector`, which was undefined. I was thinking that was the element itself. I did find that rather odd =D